# How to identify project type from project folder

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently i have received a project as a zip. I have unzipped and now i want to import the same in eclipse. But am unable to identify what type of project(maven, java, gradle, etc) it is. I have tried importing as existing project into work-space. But its not identifying as a project when searching in eclipse.

For maven projects, it will have a pom.xml, this one don't have one.
Similarly is there any other ways to identify what type of project it is from the project folder?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It will be identified as an existing project only if there is a `.project` inside the directory your  are trying to import

Comment: .project is not present in the folder. Its actually an old project. I need to analyse the process in it. So i want to import to eclipse. Since i am unable to identify the project type am not able to import

Comment: Check what files are present inside root of that project. if pom.xml is present you can infer its a maven project. If build.sbt, then its an sbt project. If build.gradle, You can know its a gradle project.

Comment: If you simply want to analyse it why don't you just create a new empty project and link the folder you received as source since the folder is missing information files like `.project` , `.pom`.

Comment: @Sangeeta, its not a maven, gradle or sbt project. But it has a build.xml and template.mf.

Comment: @catchingUp, yes we can do that, there will be multiple workarounds to solve this issue. But i would like to know the type, because I want to follow the correct process

Comment: @Sheljithkrishnan build.xml files are present in ant projects.

Comment: @Sangeeta, thanks... its ant project....

Comment: @catchingUp thanks for the quick replies :)

Comment: If there are some other ways to identify the other project types, you can post it here so that it might be useful for somebody else also.

Comment: @Sangeeta, a small doubt. my package name is com.abc.xyz, present in src/main/java. when am importing as ant project, the main.java.com.abc.xyz becomes the project and am getting error for all the java files for package name mismatch. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: if it's `src/main/java` I suspect that it might be a maven project because that's the default project structure for a maven project

Comment: @catchingUp, ok... another doubt, in that case will i have a build.xml? also i should have a pom.xml also right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received partial answer from the commends of @Sangeeta and @carchingUp. I want to add all details to a single answer so that it will be helpful to others.

Inputs from Sangeeta:  if pom.xml is present you can infer its a maven project. If build.sbt, then its an sbt project. If build.gradle, You can know its a gradle project and build.xml for ant projects

In my case i was having build.xml from which we can identify as ant project.

When you import the project as ant project to eclipse and if you have the below scenario,
 "package name is com.abc.xyz, present in src/main/java and when importing as ant project, main.java.com.abc.xyz becomes the project and am getting error for all the java files for package name mismatch", follow the below steps.

1. right click the src folder >build path >remove from build path
2. right click the java folder > build path > use as source folder.